# HTML entities into mysql request (Dolibarr)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, request, dolibarr

To do a dev into the ERP Dolibarr, I need to make some requests to the mysql database.

One of it cannot work properly cause some characters are replaced by html entities (EDIT):

Here's my request:

```
SELECT MIN(rang) FROM dolibarr.llx_propaldet WHERE fk_propal = $propalId AND rang >  :rank AND special_code = 104777 AND description <> 'Sous-total'
```

And what is really sent if I do a var_dump of my request:

```
SELECT MIN(rang) FROM dolibarr.llx_propaldet WHERE fk_propal = 3 AND rang &gt;  $rank AND special_code = 104777 AND description &lt;&gt; &#39;Sous-total&#39;
```

Some info that might help you:
- the database is encoded in latin 1
- when I create my PDO connexion I precise that statement `:PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'` so it does encode into UTF-8.
- I've tried the mb_convert_encoding() function with UTF-8 as second parameter without success.

Comment: That isn't replacing some characters by ASCII characters; it's repacing some ASCII characters by html entities

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Are you running an `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` call against your query anywhere?

Comment: No I'm not, I have compartmentalized my code by creating a new class so it's not mixed with Dolibarr core code. And then I don't run those two functions.